# Integer values in a dictionary to be stored in a plist

Tags: plist, nsdictionary

What processes are involved in storing a bunch of integer values into an NSDictionary that can then be saved as a plist?

Then how would one read that plist back into an NSDictionary and then get the values of of them?

I want to store a bunch of values and then read them back in on app relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

for storing integer values in dictionary ---

```
// saves integer as NSString.
NSString *str = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%d", 234 (integer value)];
```

now save above integer value str into dictionary as--

```
// saves your integer value into dictionary..
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] setObject:str forkey:@"intervalue"];
```

retrieving integer value from NSDictionay -----

```
//got the value in string format
NSString *str = [dict objectforkey:@"integervalue"];

// from this we got the original integer value from the string...
NSInteger integerValue = [str intValue];
```